# How to show the path for an element in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My laptop has visual studio code and it has a little plugin I guess that shows you where you are, so for example

```
function myfunction(){
 if(hello == true){
   var hello =  console.log("how are you") //if you click here
} else{
 consoe.log(":(")
}
```

shows in the top bar something like:

```
myfunction> if(true) > var hello
```

My work PC doesnt have it. I was wondering how can activate this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called `breadcrumbs`. You can enable int by `View > Toggle Breadcrumbs` command or via the `breadcrumbs.enabled` setting.

reference: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_26#_breadcrumbs